# Remove spam from loop command in batch file

Tags: batch-file, scripting

This is what I'm currently doing, and it works...but it's not pretty.

```
:scan<br>
echo "Running scan again..."<br>
for /F %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /query /s SERVER /fo list /tn "TASK" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /c "Running"') do if "%%I" 
== "3" goto :scan
```

If it gets a return of 3, it repeats itself over and over until the result changes.

That's working. What I'm wondering is, how do I make it so that it doesn't spam the window with `Running scan again...` over and over until it ends? Can I just have the one instance of `Running scan again...` be shown, but have the task continue?

Comment: using a second label?

Comment: Use the `CLS` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to elaborate on Stephan's response.  Put another label below the text you want to omit, then change your `goto` to point to that.  For example, see the `:scannolabel` changes below

```
:scan
echo "Running scan again..."
:scannolabel
for /F %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /query /s SERVER /fo list /tn "TASK" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /c "Running"') do if "%%I" == "3" goto :scannolabel
```

Comment: The colon is not needed before the label with the `GOTO` command.

Comment: good point for the OP.  I elected not to change anything that wasn't required for the solution but should have mentioned that as well.